# JavaScript For Loop continuing beyond condition

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes an array of coordinates and creates a path for use with Google Maps API. Worked great, but suddenly it seems to have decided to continue looping beyond the condition and I'm not sure what to do or why it's doing it. I've looked at it over and over again and it looks right to me, so Idk...

```
parseCoordinates = function (
    coordinates) {
    var paths = [];

    for (var i = 0, coordinate = null; coordinate = coordinates[i], i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);

        paths.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude));
    }

    return paths;
},
```

In the test case I'm using the coordinates array has seven elements and when I output `i` to the console it starts from zero and reaches six, but then decides to continue after that which ends up causing null reference errors. Can someone point me to what's happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide an example input that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, got it. Turns out my JSON data was containing two null `coordinates` objects at the end which is why it was throwing the error trying to loop them. I just need to do a null check before I use the for loop, which is what I was doing everywhere else I was using the for loops which is probably why I wasn't getting errors. Sorry to waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

You set `coordinate = coordinates[i]` before you check `i < coordinates.length`.

Comment: any idea what causes the null reference errors?

Comment: He's setting `coordinate = coordinates[7]`, even though `coordinates[7]` is undefined.

Comment: Something still doesn't feel right. I have other for loops that follow the same pattern and they work fine, for example: `(var i = 0, lead = null; lead = data.leads[i], i < data.leads.length; i++)`; `(var i = 0, job = null; job = data.jobs[i], i < data.jobs.length; i++)`; `(var i = 0, vehicle = null; vehicle = data.vehicles[i], i < data.vehicles.length; i++)`. Why would those work, but the one above not? Or are those going to break in the future as well? Should I flip the position of the condition and the assignment?

Comment: that sets `coordinate` to `undefined`, but it doesn't throw any errors